# Go to link using if condition using Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm just trying to get myself here "http://192.168.1.103:30000/?k=23&v=capture" when an if condition meet its requirement.

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
// I purposely don't include the ssid and ssid1 here
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  pinMode(1, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  WiFi.softAP(ssid1, password1);
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  String link = "http://192.168.1.103:30000/?k=23&v=capture";
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  int var = digitalRead(1);
  if (var == HIGH) {
    client.print(link);
  }
```

Let's say:

1. I already run Chrome.
2. How can that link above be called without even typing it on Chrome? I want to connect to it automatically.

Any method you could teach? I got the feeling this code itself is wrong.
Thanks.

## -- EDIT --

NEW CODE FOR UNO

```
//language c++

#include <Servo.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define I2C_ADDR 0x3F // Scanning address
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(I2C_ADDR, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE); // Set the LCD I2C address
Servo Servo1;
int servopin = 9;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // initialize the lcd for 16 chars 2 lines, turn on backlight
  lcd.backlight(); // finish with backlight on
  lcd.setCursor(3, 0); //Start at character 4 on line 0
  lcd.print("WAITING...");
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); // pin LaserLight
  pinMode(11, INPUT); // pin LaserDetector
  pinMode(10, INPUT); // pin PIR
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); // pin Servo
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); // MCU PIN GPIO2
  Servo1.attach(servopin);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
  boolean inputlaser = digitalRead(11);
  boolean inputpir = digitalRead(10);
  Serial.println(inputlaser);
  Serial.println(inputpir);
  if (inputlaser < 1) {
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("camera on");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("robber!");
    delay(5000);
    Servo1.write(180);
  } else if (inputpir > 0) {
    Servo1.write(180);
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("robber inside!");
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    lcd.print("HELP ROBBER!");
    delay(500);
  } else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
    lcd.print("standby...");
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

NEW CODE FOR MCU

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

char server[] = "192.168.1.103";
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  WiFi.softAP(ssid1, password1);
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  boolean var = digitalRead(4);
  if (var == HIGH) {
    client.connect(server, 30000);
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make your API request:
    client.println("GET /?k=23&v=capture");
    client.println("Host: 192.168.1.103");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
  Serial.println(digitalRead(4));
}
```

Comment: please give more information on your problem. What do you meant by i run chrome?where did you run chrome? from arduino? Your question says you are not good in website concept. whats the cause for feeling that your code is wrong, please provide your output that you get now, when you run the above program

Comment: oh yeah i forgot, i run chrome manually and i think i solved it but i encounter new problem... i use UNO and MCU

the concept i made is like this :
1. i use UNO for processing input and output
2. i use MCU to connect to my smartphone using the link and parameter above mentioned
3. so when sensor reacted it gave input to my UNO aaand give input to my MCU and then when MCU got input from UNO it run the link and parameter above for the smartphone to begin recording
4. but my smartphone record automatically after the compiling and uploading complete
5. i realize the chrome isn't needed

Comment: still you haven't mentioned new problem? But i think you are confused about some facts.  i will explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand a fact that you doesn't need google chrome for requesting a website.

```
 client.println("GET /?k=23&v=capture");
 client.println("Host: 192.168.1.103");
```

What you do in the above line is that you request for `/?k=23&v=capture` addressed content in the ip address `192.168.1.103`, Actully this is what you do when you use a google chrome. On PC you require a google chrome (or any other browser) for web site request because its difficult to request using commands each time (Think of requesting for a single page using a hell of http commands instead of using chrome, Ohh that's mess). So understand chrome isn't needed to access a site.

Comment: accept and upvote if my post was helpful, let it help somene with similar doubt